# Which is normal percentage usage of internal cache for WiredTiger engine?

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I use mongoDB WiredTiger v3.4.1. Current stat of cache usage in mongostat is 80%(**used** field). Is it normal or this value should be lower?

Could you tell me where I can get normal values for all stats?